# How to decrease the long press duration to show the crosshair for Shinobi iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I would like to make it easier for the user to show/hide the crosshair on the chart.  How do I decrease the long press duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#import "SChartCanvas.h"
#import "SChartCanvasOverlay.h"

@interface SChartCanvasOverlay (LongPress)
- (void) changeLongPressDelay:(CFTimeInterval)time;
@end

@implementation SChartCanvasOverlay(LongPress)

- (void) changeLongPressDelay:(CFTimeInterval)time
{
    [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration: time];
}

@end
```

The methods above should allow you to change the delay time on the long press like this:

```
[chart.canvas.overlay changeLongPressDelay:0.2];
```

Comment: Thanks.  Found a similar solution here: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2013/9/programmatically-showing-chart-crosshair-43-tooltip/